# How do I play an FM demodulated sample on the sound card in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, signal-processing

I have created a Common Lisp library binding for libbladerf and can receive signals in Common Lisp. I have a function that demodulates an FM signal and is defined as follows:

```lisp
(defun fm-demodulate-sc16-q11-samples (device frequency)
  (configure-channel device (channel-rx 0) frequency 1000 40000000 30)
  (init-sync device)
  (enable-module device (channel-rx 0) t)
  (with-foreign-objects ((rx-samples :uint16 8192)
             (metadata :pointer))
    (let ((status (bladerf_sync_rx (mem-ref device :pointer) rx-samples 4096 metadata 5000))
      (samples-array (make-array 8192 :element-type 'float :initial-element 0.0 :fill-pointer 0)))
      (if (< status 0)
      (error "Failed to recieve IQ samples error: ~S" status)
      (progn
          (loop for i below 4096 by 4
         do
           (let* ((previous-i (mem-aref rx-samples :int16 (1+ i)))
              (previous-q (mem-aref rx-samples :int16 i))
              (current-i  (mem-aref rx-samples :int16 (+ i 3)))
              (current-q  (mem-aref rx-samples :int16 (+ i 2)))
              (previous-complex (complex previous-i previous-q))
              (current-complex (complex current-i current-q))
              (dif-complex (* (conjugate previous-complex) current-complex)))
             (vector-push (atan-complex-number dif-complex) samples-array)))
          samples-array)))))
```

I then pass this to cl-portaudio using the following code:

```lisp
 (defconstant +frames-per-buffer+ 1024)
 (defconstant +sample-rate+ 44100d0)
 (defconstant +sample-format+ :float)
 (defconstant +num-channels+ 2)

 (defun play-demodulated-fm () 
  (with-audio 
    (with-default-audio-stream (astream +num-channels+ +num-channels+ :sample-format +sample-format+ :sample-rate +sample-rate+ :frames-per-buffer +frames-per-buffer+) 
      (dotimes (i 20)
         (write-stream astream (fm-demodulate-sc16-q11-samples *dev* 863000000)))))
```

When I play this all I hear is a clipping sound and the following warning:

```
array is copied and/or coerced, lisp type is T, requested CFFI type is FLOAT
```

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:8432:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

What is the correct way of playing an FM demodulated signal with cl-portaudio?

Comment: https://github.com/filonenko-mikhail/cl-portaudio

Comment: I have edited my question please change the status

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play a simple tone with cl-portaudio and got the very same error as you reported:

```
array is copied and/or coerced, lisp type is T, requested CFFI type is FLOAT
```

After a long night of trying and digging the net I finally cooked the following piece of code making a sound. Probably not 'CleanCode', but should do as a start.

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (ql:quickload "cl-portaudio"))

(defconstant +sample-rate+ 44100d0)
(defconstant +sample-format+ :float)
(defconstant +input-channels+ 0)
(defconstant +output-channels+ 1)
(defconstant +sound-frequency+ 800)

(defconstant +angle-per-tick+ (* 2d0 pi (/ +sound-frequency+ +sample-rate+)))

(defconstant +audio-buffer-size+ 4096
  "The number of samples in the audio buffer.")

(defconstant +audio-buffer-time+ (* +audio-buffer-size+ (/ +sample-rate+))
  "The total time the information in the audio buffer represents, in seconds.")

(defun make-audio-buffer ()
  (make-array +audio-buffer-size+
    :element-type 'single-float
    :initial-element 0.0))

(defun make-sine-wave (&optional (angle 0d0))
  (loop
    with buffer = (make-audio-buffer)
    for i from 0 below +audio-buffer-size+
    for cur-angle = (+ angle (* i +angle-per-tick+))
    do
       (setf (aref buffer i) (coerce (sin cur-angle) 'single-float))
    finally
       (return-from make-sine-wave (values buffer (mod cur-angle (* 2 pi))))))

(defun play-note()
  (portaudio:with-audio
    (portaudio:with-default-audio-stream
        (audio-stream +input-channels+ +output-channels+
         :sample-format :float
         :sample-rate +sample-rate+
         :frames-per-buffer +audio-buffer-size+)
      (loop
        for i from 1 to 8
        with angle = 0d0
        do
           (multiple-value-bind
             (buffer new-angle)
               (make-sine-wave angle)        
             (portaudio:write-stream audio-stream buffer)
             (setf angle new-angle))))))
```